# Json output display print pretty

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to display print pretty.  Having a hard time remembering the line. Google isn't giving me much help

```
$json_output = json_encode($json_output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$JSON_output = json_encode($JSON_output,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: You can also set `header('content-type':application/json)` in top of your php file, the output automatically show as pretty print

Comment: look like fake questions and user, there just for scoring...should be banned

Comment: Im not a fake user...??